# vue js transition sidebar push content

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions

I have a sidebar, and main content container.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <sidebar-item/>
    <transition name="fade-kiosk-list">
      <kiosk-list v-if="isOpen"/>
    </transition>
    <main class="container">
      <router-view/>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my transition style:

```
.fade-kiosk-list-enter-active,
.fade-kiosk-list-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-kiosk-list-enter {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.fade-kiosk-list-enter-to {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.fade-kiosk-list-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

The sidebar effect works well, but I want to also add transition for the main container, to be like 'push' effect.
How can I 'listen' to the transition event of the sidebar?

Thanks.

Comment: Emit an event when `isOpen` changes?

Comment: Found any solution to this?